# getting "broken pipe" at about 1.2 MB files (from HP-UX to macOS) ... how fix?

Tags: ssh, scp, hp-ux

I'm getting "broken pipe" while trying to scp files larger than about 1.5 MB from a remote HP-UX system to my local Mac.

Any suggestions, please?

Small files work ok, up to about 1.1 MB or so.

I'm connected via an OpenVPN connection.

I just noticed that if I connect via an old-style VPN (using PSK, but that's as much as I know about it :), I can transfer the large files successfully (and more slowly).

I did an 'scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG3' with the 1.1 MB good file, and the 1.5 MB bad file ... the trace is below.

The first trace is the failed attempt.  About 173 lines in is the point where it differs from the good attempt.
(Only the remaining portion of the good trace is shown below.)

I've tried the following, in various combinations:

-l 2000

-o ServerAliveCountMax=5 -o ServerAliveInterval=2

-o IPQoS=throughput

-o IPQoS=0x0

Trace of bad scp:
'''

```
sf:tt sieler$ scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 ozma:source/rose/cxform .
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/sieler/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ozma port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2+sftpfilecontrol-v1.3-hpn13v12
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2+sftpfilecontrol-v1.3-hpn13v12 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ozma:22 as 'sieler'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ozma
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p4b4zkfgHwRyomxCiUehCowkgA11sna8ko7mWNgrhQA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ozma
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.84.3.15
debug1: Host 'ozma' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/sieler/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:2kIKCd[...]
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:2kIKCdm9l[...]
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/sieler/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:2kIKCdm9l[...]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:2kIKCdm9lMtJfy/HXckvn2r1Vq3JIbX[...]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ozma ([10.84.3.15]:22).
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env CDPATH
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env COLS
debug3: Ignored env COLUMNS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env EXINIT
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env LINES
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env BASH_FUNC_prman%%
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug1: Sending command: scp -f source/rose/cxform
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 65536
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
cxform                                                                                              0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETAdebug2: channel 0: window 1998827 sent adjust 98325
debug2: channel 0: window 1990656 sent adjust 106496
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
                     <--- first difference.  Good session had another "sent adjust" like the above line
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 6/7/8 sock -1 cc -1)

debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to ozma closed by remote host.
Broken pipeTransferred: sent 3004, received 1092812 bytes, in 1.0 seconds

Bytes per second: sent 2982.7, received 1085052.8
debug1: Exit status -1
sf:tt sieler$
```

'''

Trace of good session (partial, from point of difference):
'''

```
debug2: channel 0: window 1966080 sent adjust 131072
tapesd                                                  100% 1123KB   1.1MB/s   00:01    
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/8 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3064, received 1153540 bytes, in 1.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2490.8, received 937736.8
debug1: Exit status 0
sf:tt sieler$
```

'''

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the remote end is killing the connection. My guess would be a timeout somewhere in the chain - it may be that there are SSHD settings to tweak on the `osma` host?

Otherwise, have you tried using `rsync` instead of `scp`? It supports resuming transfers so even if you had to run the command multiple times it would get there eventually.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  Unfortunately, it also fails (and also at varying places during the transfer):   rsync  ozma:source/rose/RO9K_cc_20.tar.Z RO
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (1081545 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (43 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at  [...]